# waitForElementVisible on Nightwatch not working

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I am new to testing and just trying a basic login test which is not working, for some reason my DOM doesn't appear to be loaded even with longer wait time. I am using firefox webdriver (gecko).

Here's the code below:-

```
module.exports = {
'Login hub' : function loginHub(browser) {
  browser
    .url('http://hub.rdfzxishan.cn')
    .assert.title('Hub | Akiraku')
    .waitForElementVisible('body', 10000)
    .setValue('input[name=email]', 'wangdeli@rdfz.cn')
    .setValue('input[type=password]', 'testtest')
    .submitForm('button[type=submit]')
  },

  'Home page' : function success(browser) {
    browser
    .assert.containsText(".email", "wangdeli@rdfz.cn")
    .pause(100000)
    .end();
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding `autocomplete="on|off"` attribute to all the password inputs in your html code, like:

```
<input type="password" autocomplete="off" />
```